# Expand accordion on button click

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I am using angular material expansion panel and am trying to set the accordion to be expanded if there are validation errors on a button click. The problem I am having is when the user clicks on the minimize arrow, then because the expanded property is already true this means that the accordion does not expand.

Here is my code

**Wrapper component**

*Mat accordion HTML*

```
<mat-accordion>
    <mat-expansion-panel (opened)="data.panelOpenState === true" (closed)="data.panelOpenState === false" [expanded]="data.expanded">
        <mat-expansion-panel-header (click)="stateValue()">
            <mat-panel-title>
                {{ data?.title }}
            </mat-panel-title>
        </mat-expansion-panel-header>
        <ng-content></ng-content>
    </mat-expansion-panel>
</mat-accordion>
```

*Mat accordion TS*

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { SidePanelAccordianData } from './side-panel-accordian.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-side-panel-accordian',
  templateUrl: './side-panel-accordian.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./side-panel-accordian.component.scss']
})
export class SidePanelAccordianComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() data: SidePanelAccordianData;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  stateValue() {
    this.data.panelOpenState = !this.data.panelOpenState;
  }

}
```

*Mat accordion model*

```
export class SidePanelAccordianData {
  public title: string = '';
  public panelOpenState: boolean;
  public expanded: boolean;


  constructor(args) {
    this.title = args.title;
    this.panelOpenState = args.panelOpenState;
    this.expanded = args.expanded;
  }
}
```

*component html where I am using the accordion*

```
<app-side-panel-accordian [data]="{title:'Title', panelOpenState: true, expanded: secondDriverExpanded}">
    <div class="inner-row-data">
      <form-input [formStatus]="formStatus" [parentFormGroup]="setupForm" [data]="{
        formControlName: 'secondDriverName',
        name: 'secondDriverName',
      }" (onBlur)="setSecondDriverDetails('name')">
      </form-input>
    </div>
</app-side-panel-accordian>


<form-button type="button" (click)="onNext()">Next</form-button>
```

*component ts where I am using the accordion*

```
public secondDriverExpanded = true;

onNext() {
 <!--if there are validation errors-->
 this.secondDriverExpanded = true;
}
```

So when a user arrives on the page the accordion is expanded which is correct however if the user clicks on the HTML arrow to minimize the accordion as seen in the below image then the expanded property is not set to false. How can I ensure that it is set to false on the minimize so that when the next button is clicked it will expand?

[image: accordion]

Answer (score 0):

[Angular Material Expansion Panel](https://material.angular.io/components/expansion/api) extends [CdkAccordionItem](https://material.angular.io/components/expansion/api#MatExpansionPanel) and as a result it has two output properties: `closed` and `opened`. Those emitters emit when panel is closed or opened. You can use them to track current state of expansion panel.

Example usage:

```html
<mat-expansion-panel (opened)="panelOpenState = true" (closed)="panelOpenState = false">
</mat-expansion-panel>
```

```js
public panelOpenState = false;
```

As I can see you have some wrapper on expansion panel, so probably you have to define custom output to match the event emit propagation. For example:

```js
@Component({
  template: '<mat-expansion-panel (opened)="expansionStateChange.emit(true)" 
                            (closed)="expansionStateChange.emit(false)" ...'
})
class YourWrapper {
@Output expansionStateChange = new EventEmitter<boolean>();
}
```

And then use this `expansionStateChange` output to update `secondDriverExpanded` property.

Comment: I have added the wrapper component code above. Can you please assist in how I can get access to the `panelOpenState` value?

I don't beleive that I need to emit anything from the wrapper as I do have a model already. I just can't seem to get the `panelOpenState` value in the `<app-side-panel-accordian` part

Comment: First of all, the `(opened)="data.panelOpenState === true" (closed)="data.panelOpenState === false"` is just wrong, that's not how angular works. Don't expect that to work. Second, if you want to have MatExpansionPanel opened state available in external component, you **have to** communicate that state. For this, angular uses [output binding](https://angular.io/guide/inputs-outputs#sending-data-to-a-parent-component), which I described in my answer. The fact that you pass some _model_ just states that you communicate from the component to the wrapper, not the other way.